# PHP vários Insert junto com um update

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso fazer vários `insert` junto com um `update`.

No meu formulário, dei um `print_r($_POST);` para ver todas as variáveis que estão sendo enviadas.

```
Array
(
    [matricula] => 10-03793383-19
    [id_aluno] => 11
    [id_curso] => 1
    [valorCurso] => 1000.00
    [valorPago] => 0.00
    [parcelas] => 2
    [formaPagamento] => 6
    [formaTaxas] => 0,00
    [id_polo] => 1
    [poloComissao] => 0,00
    [aMatricula] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10-03793383-19
            [1] => 10-03793383-19
        )

    [aParcelas] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 de 2
            [1] => 2 de 2
        )

    [aParcelasForma] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 6
        )

    [aParcelasVencimento] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-08-02
            [1] => 2019-08-09
        )

    [aParcelasValor] => Array
        (
            [0] => 500.00
            [1] => 500.00
        )

    [button] => 
    [form] => form1
    [dataMatricula] => 2019-08-02
    [editadorPor] => Administrador
    [editadoData] => 2019-08-02 07:08:27
    [status] => A
    [ID_Matricula] => 1
)
```

Do valor acima, os que vão para o `insert` são esses dados:

```
    [aMatricula] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10-03793383-19
            [1] => 10-03793383-19
        )

    [aParcelas] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 de 2
            [1] => 2 de 2
        )

    [aParcelasForma] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 6
        )

    [aParcelasVencimento] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-08-02
            [1] => 2019-08-09
        )

    [aParcelasValor] => Array
        (
            [0] => 500.00
            [1] => 500.00
        )
```

Como devo fazer para o `insert` inserir os registros de acordo com a quantidade de **PARCELAS**?

Codigo PHP:

```
if ((isset($_POST["form"])) && ($_POST["form"] == "form1")) {

    echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';

    $rs1 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE matriculas SET
            matricula=?,
            id_aluno=?,
            id_curso=?,
        valorCurso=?,
            parcelas=?,
            valorPago=?,
        formaPagamento=?,
            formaTaxas=?,
            id_polo=?,
        poloComissao=?,
            dataMatricula=?,
            editadorPor=?,
        editadoData=?,
        status=?
        WHERE
            ID_Matricula=? ");

    $rs1->bind_param('ssssssssssssssi',
      $_POST['matricula'],
      $_POST['id_aluno'],
      $_POST['id_curso'],
      $_POST['valorCurso'],
      $_POST['parcelas'],
      $_POST['valorPago'],
      $_POST['formaPagamento'],
      $_POST['formaTaxas'],
      $_POST['id_polo'],
      $_POST['poloComissao'],
      $_POST['dataMatricula'],
      $_POST['editadorPor'],
      $_POST['editadoData'],
      $_POST['status'],
        $_POST['ID_Matricula']
        );

    $rs1->execute();


    $rs2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO financ_receita (matricula, parcela, valor, dataLanc, dataVenci, formaEntrada) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

    $rs2->bind_param('ssssss',
      $_POST['aMatricula'],
      $_POST['aParcelas'],
      $_POST['aParcelasValor'],
      date("Y-m-d"),
      $_POST['aParcelasVencimento'],
      $_POST['aParcelasForma']
    );

    $rs2->execute();


    if (($rs1->errno) or ($rs2->errno)) {
        echo 'Erro rs1: ', $rs1->error;
      echo 'Erro rs1: ', $rs2->error;
    } else {
        echo "<script>window.location='sucesso.php'</script>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para quem tiver a mesma dúvida, segue a resposta.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['parcelas']; $i++) {
      $rs2 = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO financ_receita (id_cadastro, matricula, parcela, valor, dataLanc, dataVenci, formaEntrada) VALUES (
         '".$_POST['id_cadastro'][$i]."',
         '".$_POST['aMatricula'][$i]."',
         '".$_POST['aParcelas'][$i]."',
         '".$_POST['aParcelasValor'][$i]."',
         '".date('Y-m-d')."',
         '".$_POST['aParcelasVencimento'][$i]."',
         '".$_POST['aParcelasForma'][$i]."'
      )");
```

Answer (score -2):

Se eu entendi a sua pergunta, você deve fazer `INSERT` de acordo com o número de parcelas, então deve iterar `parcelas` e fazer os `INSERT`. <strike>Aconselho você utilizar o `pdo` como objeto do banco, `mysqli` já está fora das versões mais atuais do PHP.</strike>

Comment: O conteúdo está mais para um comentário do que uma resposta.

Comment: Essa informação está incorreta. mysqli não será descontinuado (a não ser que um dia surja alguma versão melhorada, como aconteceu com a lib mysql que foi deixando de ser usada pela versão melhorada mysqli que é a atual) e o PDO é inferior ao mysqli no cenário do OP. Entenda que o PDO é uma biblioteca de abstração, e o MySQLi é um wrapper puro, por consequência mais eficaz e mais abrangente em termos de funcionalidade.

Comment: Verdade @bacco confundi com as funções mysql_*